# why does it not work if I don't handle the return value of call/callcode/delegatecall？

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

This is my Contract code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;
  event CallStatus(bool);

  function callSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    if (!_e.call.gas(500000)(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n)) {
        CallStatus(false);
    } else {
        CallStatus(true);
    }// E's storage is set, D is not modified
  }
  function callSetN2(address _e, uint _n) {
      _e.call.gas(500000)(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n);
  }

  function callcodeSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    if (!_e.callcode.gas(500000)(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n)) {
        CallStatus(false);
    } else {
        CallStatus(true);
    }// D's storage is set, E is not modified
  }

  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    if (!_e.delegatecall.gas(500000)(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n)) {
        CallStatus(false);
    } else {
        CallStatus(true);
    }// D's storage is set, E is not modified
  }
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;

  function setN(uint _n) {
    n = _n;
    sender = msg.sender;
    // msg.sender is D if invoked by D's callcodeSetN. None of E's storage is updated
    // msg.sender is C if invoked by C.foo(). None of E's storage is updated
  }
}
```

**the execute environment is web3 provider connected to my geth private chain, when I use the default environment javascript VM, callsetN2 works fine.**

when i call callSetN function using parameter ("0xe143a6ecbe6374463485664aecda3d0f0a6590d6", 10), I can get right number n from E contract. then I call callSetN2 function using parameter ("0xe143a6ecbe6374463485664aecda3d0f0a6590d6", 11), I can't get right number n from E, it's still 10 not 11. why does this happen? I tried to debug the callSetN2 function,

[image: debug1]

it should execute sstore opcode, but when I step on, the pc goes to D's contract, instead 257 of E's code.

[image]

this confuses me. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. It behaves as expected in Remix as both `callSetN` and `callSetN2` correctly set the `n` property on `E`.

Comment: when I connect to web3 provider in the remix environment, deploy and call contract in the remix, I can produce this problem. when I directly deploy and call contract in the geth console, there is no problem. so I think maybe remix has a bug.

Comment: I know why. Because in the remix environment, the gasLimit setting doesn't work, so even if I set gasLimit to 500000, the transaction's real gasLimit is 25673 which is not enough to execute.